# Передача размера в процентах

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос: я написал скрипт, чтобы ширина `<div id="1"></div>` равнялась ширине `<div id="2" style="width:23%"></div>`, но  ширина передается не в процентах, а в пикселях. Как сделать, чтобы  передовалось в процентах?

**Обновление**

Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     document.getElementById('aApbarFiller').style.width=$('.pbarFiller').css('width') });
```

Comment: Вопрос в том, проценты от чего? От размера экрана?

Comment: Неважно, нужно, чтобы именно в процентах выдало.
Мне не нужно от чего-то проценты, а именно ту ширину, которая написана в стиле.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Только для случая, когда ширина прописана в HTML (как у вас)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var w = $('.pbarFiller').get(0).style.width;
  $('#aApbarFiller').get(0).style.width=w;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qaxj21k/1/)

Если прописана в CSS и нужны проценты - см. этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744450) на stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

Значение идентификатора или класса элемента не может начинаться с цифры.

Если опустить из внимания этот момент, то простейшее решение, которое вам подойдет, выглядит так:

```
$('#2').attr('style', $('#1').attr('style'));
```